# Is there a way to collapse data within a column by id in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data that has been exported from REDCap.  Since there are multiple forms, it is putting the results from different forms on different rows, but nested within the same lesion and patient ID.

I'd like to collapse the rows so each lesion id has one row with all the information.  (Some patients have more than one lesion)

What would be the best way to do this in dplyr?  I tried messing with pivot_wider but that doesn't seem right.

Here's what the data look like now:

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyverse)

data<-tribble(
  ~lesion_id, ~patient_id, ~complete, ~ct_finding, ~guess, ~malignancy,
  "747-1", 747, "complete", NA, NA, 0,
  "747-1", 747, NA, "lesion growth", NA, 0,
  "747-1", 747, NA, NA, "Non-Malignant", 0,
  "747-2", 747, "incomplete", NA, NA, 1,
  "747-2", 747, NA, "remission", NA, 1,
  "747-2", 747, NA, NA, "Non-Malignant", 1
)
```

...and here's what I'd like it to turn into:

```
desired_data<-tribble(
  ~lesion_id, ~patient_id, ~complete, ~ct_finding, ~guess, ~malignancy,
  "747-1", 747, "complete", "lesion growth", "Non-Malignant", 0,
  "747-2", 747, "incomplete", "remission", "Non-Malignant", 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that your `malignancy` column is invariant within each `*_id` pair, then you can do this:

```r
data %>%
  summarize(
    across(everything(), na.omit),
    .by = c(lesion_id, patient_id, malignancy)
  )
# # A tibble: 2 × 6
#   lesion_id patient_id malignancy complete   ct_finding    guess        
#   <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>      <chr>         <chr>        
# 1 747-1            747          0 complete   lesion growth Non-Malignant
# 2 747-2            747          1 incomplete remission     Non-Malignant
```

(This will fail if you have an uneven number of non-`NA` values in the columns.)

Answer (score 0):

in base R you could do:

```
aggregate(.~lesion_id + patient_id + malignancy, data, na.omit, na.action = identity)

  lesion_id patient_id malignancy   complete    ct_finding         guess
1     747-1        747          0   complete lesion growth Non-Malignant
2     747-2        747          1 incomplete     remission Non-Malignant
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data |>
  group_by(lesion_id, patient_id, malignancy) |>
  fill(complete:guess, .direction = "downup") |>
  ungroup() |>
  distinct()


  lesion_id patient_id complete   ct_finding    guess    malignancy
  <chr>          <dbl> <chr>      <chr>         <chr>         <dbl>
1 747-1            747 complete   lesion growth Non-Mal…          0
2 747-2            747 incomplete remission     Non-Mal…          1
```